# Retrofit with QueryMap

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have some request with the same **endpoint** but parameter and return type are different.

I used `@QueryMap` for the parameter but I don't know how to write the return type:

Must I write:

```
@GET("xxx")
Call<List<A1>> groupList1(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
@GET("xxx")
Call<List<A2>> groupList2(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
@GET("xxx")
Call<List<A3>> groupList3(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
....
```

or there is a shorter solution?

Comment: What happens if you name those methods differently and call those endpoints?

Comment: That solution will work but them only difference parameter and return type. Can I have a solution better and shorter ?

Comment: I don't see the problem actually. If you were to make a single endpoint you would have to parse data on demand and that would complicate code even more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JsonElement` response type

```
 @GET("xxx")
    Call<JsonElement> groupList(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
```

Every call you will receive `JsonElement` which you can convert to `JsonObject` or `JsonArray` or even `String`. You can parse/deserealize it according to the your content

```
public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
      JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
      //JsonArray array = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
      //JsonObject Obj = jsonElement .getAsJsonObject();
}
```