# Sending an array of items to an URL

Tags: android, retrofit2

Am using Retrofit2 newly, i have to form below request type dynamically

http://"BASE_URL"/confirmOrder?config.items[0].id:12939837&config.items[0].opt1Id:0&config.items[1].id:12939837&config.items[1].opt1Id:0

Am able to form base url , but problem is how do i send array of items dynamically in url , array of items may be 1 to 10

array has to appended in url

```
config.items[0].id:12939837
config.items[0].opt1Id:0
config.items[1].id:12939837
config.items[1].opt1Id:0
....
....
```

because our server accepts only in this form

Comment: whats the type of array you want to send?

Comment: You may check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766953/retrofit-with-querymap

Answer (score 0):

well if by array you mean `String` or `int` type arrays that could be done using retrofit

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("v1.1/yourURL")
Call<Your_Model> userLogin( @Field("data[]") String[] data
                                 );
```

And then simply call the method , and pass the method

```
String names[] = {"Blah","Blaaah","Blaaaaah"};
userCall = service.userLogin(names);
    userCall.enqueue(new Callback<Your_Model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Your_Model> call, Response<Your_Model> response) {
            if (response.body().getStatus()==1){


                Toast.makeText(OtherActivity.this, "Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.d("ResponceFromServer" ,"Responce" +response.body().getMessage());


            }
            else {
                Log.d("ResponceFromServer" ,"Responce" +response.body().getMessage());


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Your_Model> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.d("ResponceFromServer" ,"Responce OnFailure" +t.toString());

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: how to send different keys, here am using different keys, in your example data[] - key is same but not same in my case

Comment: @Vishwanath.M well only thing which matters is the `type` , if you have all the int data then its good , you could send all the array , and control it in the backend